# Eclipse crash, ieframe.dll

Tags: eclipse, crash, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, ieframe.dll

I am using Tizen IDE for wearable and after choosing new empty workspace it crashes, any ideas? I have up-to-date Internet Explorer.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fef5e26890, pid=7860, tid=1880
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ieframe.dll+0x146890]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: it is a permission issue, are you an administrator?

Comment: yes, i am the administrator

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue with LPCXpresso (which is Eclipse-based too). The problem is also discussed here: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&p=235343. They say, it's related to a specific Windows Update (KB2977629) and uninstalling helps. To avoid tampering with Windows Update, I simply changed the Web Browser used by Eclipse from internal to external, which solved my problem. Might also work in Tizen IDE.

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser -> "Use external Web Browser"

Comment: might work for eclipse, but not for other applications having the same issue. my application is using SWT and it uses the ie-frame at some point

Comment: Had this problem for Eclipse; I did the same thing MarkusM - "Use external Web Browser" and then picked Firefox explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading IE to IE10 did the job.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the related eclipse bug report:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444005

Note that i can also see this bug on eclipse 4.4, regardless of what the original reporter wrote.

Comment: I also have this with Kepler (4.3)