# I cannot seem to get android studio running, tried changing path, reinstalling java(oracle) and reinstalling android

Tags: android, crash

I cannot seem to get android studio running, tried changing path, reinstalling java(oracle) and reinstalling android studio but to no avail. The thing that intrigues me most is that the logs state openjdk version 1.8 when I am using oracle's version and I have never installed openjdk.

log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1GT7O5RajNnVkJBSUp3elRyS28/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking around at your issue and seem to find many other people running into the same problem but with other software like eclipse. The general solution I have seen is to uninstall the Microsoft KB2977629 patch. Or it is a hardware issue and you have to update/reinstall your graphics driver.

Hardware fix:
[JVM Crash - "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406681/jvm-crash-exception-access-violation)

Check out:
[Eclipse crash, ieframe.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822790/eclipse-crash-ieframe-dll)

Talend Forge:
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=145371